# Android developer "Upload new APK to Production 99% complete" and stuck

Tags: android, upload, console, google-play, apk

I have attempted to upload an app via the Google Play Developer Console for the last two days, but the apk uploads until "99% complete" in firefox or until "processing" in chrome and the is stuck.

[image]

This is not my first app. I have uploaded and published two others without incident.

I have attempted the upload with following with all the same result:

*Firefox 28.0 (Ubuntu 13.10)

*Firefox 28.0 Incognito (Ubuntu 13.10)

*Chromium Version 33.0.1750.152 (Ubuntu 13.10)

*Chromium Version 33.0.1750.152 (Ubuntu 13.10) Incognito

*Chrome mobile 33.0.1750.166 on Galaxy Nexus Android 4.2.1 phone

*Chrome (Windows 8)

Logs start out fine:

POST https://play.google.com/apps/publish/upload [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 537ms] POST https://clients2.google.com/uploadstats [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1402ms] POST https://clients2.google.com/uploadstats [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1457ms] POST https://play.google.com/apps/publish/upload

then it hits 99% complete and these errors start posting:

POST https://play.google.com/apps/publish/upload [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 3816ms] POST https://play.google.com/apps/publish/upload [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 739ms] POST https://play.google.com/apps/publish/upload [HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable 668ms] POST https://play.google.com/apps/publish/upload

I also tried advancing the version in the AndroidManifest.xml.

As a test I added the apk in question to the Amazon Appstore. No difficulties. The apk uploaded seamlessly. Google Play Store issue?

Also tried adding a new application in the developer console and then uploading the apk.

Also tried starting from scratch and rebuilding the app in Eclipse and then attempted to upload the new apk. No luck

I have been emailing with Google Help. 8 days ago they asked for the apk in question and HAR file generated when the upload gets stuck. I sent both. They replied they were looking into the issue. A few days later this question came alive with others experiencing the same issues! I emailed again that I was still encountering issues.

Then on March 19th they responded and asked for:

> - A screenshot of the error message.
> - The APK you're attempting to upload
> - The browser versions you were able to test with and OS type that you are using.
> - Information from the browser's error console or http logs.
> - What steps did you take to reproduce this issue?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked any error prompt appear?

Comment: @SachinShelke the upload never completes. I cancel it after it has sat at 99% for over an hour and receive no error message. I simply drops back to the developer console without uploading. (The apk is only 5.5mb if that has any importance).

Comment: try clearing all history of browser. I am not sure but hopefully it will help.

Comment: @SachinShelke cleared the cache. Sadly, same result. So odd. I had no difficulty with the first two apps uploaded.

Comment: I'm stuck on 0% too. It's been fine all week; up to 10 hours or so ago.

Comment: I contacted Google using this URL: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing

Comment: There is a related bug report here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67226

Comment: On March 13th I emailed Google support they responded asking for the: - The APK you're attempting to upload - HAR file generated when the upload gets stuck. To generate a HAR file: 1. Chrome Settings Menu -> Tools -> Developer Tools -> select Network tab 2. Reproduce the error 3. Right-click in the Network tab, select 'Save as HAR with content' 4. Send us the downloaded file. Which I sent along to them.

Comment: On March 14th Google's response after sending the files was: "Thanks for your reply and the additional details. We've documented your experience, and our team is currently investigating the issue. We're working hard to get this issue resolved for you as soon as possible. We'll let you know as soon as we have a solution. Thanks again for your patience, and we apologize for any inconvenience this has caused." So I suppose it may be an issue on their end? Will update when more information is forthcoming. (no further responses from them past this point)

Comment: I've uploaded 51 versions of my current code before, and others as well. The first time I experience this problem was today. Pretty sure it's their issue...

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you guys, since today. I am in Germany. Any updates on how to get around this issue? Maybe a workaround for in the mean time? I really need to upload an update, and it is not like this isn't time sensitive either, every day I wait is costing me money.. fix it google!

Comment: same problem in greece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My specific issue was identified by the Google Support team:

> Our specialists have found that the APK was getting stuck during the
>   step where we verify the icon and the certificates.
>
> Comparing the aapt dump to your app's manifest, there are some
>   inconsistencies with the icon location. You would want to start
>   troubleshooting there. If after fixing the icon you still encounter
>   upload issues, double check your certificates and your signing
>   procedure.

The issue was entirely mine as a new and inexperienced developer.

Upon replacing the icon and redoing the key in Eclipse, the .apk in question uploaded without incident and is now published.

The Google Team also made the following suggestion for those searching for help:

> For more information on running aapt, please see the “Testing the features required by your application” section of the following article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html.

Comment: @noobProgrammer not sure what more to add. In Eclipse I re-added my icon (New->Other->Android Icon Set) (perhaps I did not "Yes to All" when I replaced the icon initially?). Then for safe measure I made a new key when I exported the signed application. That's all I did. Then the APK uploaded with no problems at all.

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in Android that affects every version of it. A developer found out about it yesterday. By malforming an apk file you can corrupt system memory and systems freezes completely. He then uploaded this malformed apk to Goople Play from different countries causing Google Play Developer Console to freeze all over the world! It was fixed for about an hour but then the developer reuploaded the apk and Google Play is down again. I think it will be fixed soon, but anyway it can lead to huge financial damages to many companies around the world.

http://ibrahimbalic.com/2014/android-os-memory-corruption-bug/

So the answer is we just have to wait...

Comment: Why would uploading an app which causes problem on Android devices also cause a problem to Google Play's ability to accept uploaded files? That would be a bit of a coincidence.  Perhaps Google took down the ability to upload apps whilst this issue could be fixed. We'll see if this turns out the be the issue.

Comment: It might be that the Android emulator that tests the app when uploaded froze as well and that might caused the error.

Comment: I just added the same answer, but I didn't see you already posted it. (I deleted mine) This is the correct answer.

Comment: too much fantasy in this explanation. it's a console bug. this story of the user that... smells like a hoax

Comment: Actually Google Bouncer crashed, because Bouncer quietly and automatically scans apps (both new and previously uploaded ones) and developer accounts in Google Play with its reputation engine and cloud infrastructure. http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/a-look-at-google-bouncer/

Answer (score 4):

It's a temporary problem, common to many users, due to google developer console website problem.
After tring many times at different hours you will finally upload your app.
This is my experience.

Here the link to the problem report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67226

Here the link to report the problem directly to Google requesting support: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=submitting

Comment: When you finally became able to upload your app? Today?

Comment: Same for me, today i wanted to update all my apps.. But in two hours, i still uploaded two of them..

Answer (score 3):

It was a problem on Google's end, and they were aware of it; <s>[there was a message on their support site](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4639475)</s> (which now appears to have been taken down) and in the Developer Console alerts:

> **Errors uploading to the Google Play Developer Console:**
>   We're currently aware of an issue impacting some developers attempting
>   to upload APKs or Images to the Google Play Developer Console. We're
>   working hard on a fix, and will provide an update once the issue is
>   resolved.

Google states it now appears to be fixed:

> **UPDATE - 2014.03.17 4:00PM PT:** 
>   This issue is now resolved. Please contact us if you see any issues
>   uploading APKs or Images.

I have been able to publish APKs and also received numerous app updates since this message was posted, so it does appear that this specific problem appears to be resolved now.

Comment: Would probably make more sense for Google to put the warning on the upload dialog, or the page it is launched from, rather than assume people will a) look for some statement somewhere or other and b) actually find it.

Comment: On my developer console, the megaphone icon on the left edge of the screen was bright orange and attracted my attention as soon as I signed in.. that's usually where they put these sort of notifications.