# Is there an alternative way to upload an apk to Google Play besides the developer console?

Tags: android, upload, apk

I am encountering an issue in uploading an apk using the Google Play Developer Console (see this question for more background: [Android developer "Upload new APK to Production 99% complete" and stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282686/android-developer-upload-new-apk-to-production-99-complete-and-stuck)

I would like to attempt any alternative upload options that may be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say that but there is no other way to upload apk. You must use developer console.

What problem you are facing, which error? You can try with other network or other machine to export and upload apk. Also you can write it to Google on support email.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is the issue I am facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282686/android-developer-upload-new-apk-to-production-99-complete-and-stuck Yes, I have tried other machines, even mobile devices, and connecting through a VPN. Yes, I have sent a request to Google support via email and am waiting a response.