# Updating Existing Android App on Play Store Gives Error

Tags: android, apk

When I update the App with the new apk. it gives the error as attached image.

says

Upload Failed, We could not save your changes, please try again

my package name is the same, same key store is used...

What will be the reasons ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem with Google Play today.

Comment: If it's known, then a link to an official statement would be nice. The only thing I've found is this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67226

Comment: @1ka I provided a link to a possible duplicate.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! I read your answer and not the general comments :-)

Comment: Google is aware of it.. see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22463003/1992342